# PHP PDO - Empty Page

Tags: mysql, pdo

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I have a problem i have this script (below) and when i access the file with right switch cases i become a white screen. the first script doesnt work the seconds works fine. i isolated the error in my opinion: the sql statement (table and columns exist)

```
<?php


    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "regressiontest";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        switch($operation){
            case "managerList": {
                $stmt = $conn->query("
                                    SELECT
                                        *
                                    FROM
                                        regressiontest.campaign_run;");

            } break;

        }


        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        $output = $stmt->fetchAll();

        switch($compute){
            case "json": {
                echo json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);              
            }
        }


    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
?>
```

And this cases works fine

```
<?php


    //check for error output
    if(isset($_GET['error'])){
        if($_GET['error'] == "false"){
            error_reporting(0);
        } else if($_GET['error'] == "true"){
            ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
        } else {
            error_reporting(0);
        }
    } else {
        error_reporting(0);
    }

    //check for timelimit
    if(isset($_GET['timelimit'])){ set_time_limit($_GET['timelimit']); } else { set_time_limit(0); }

    //check for operation
    if(isset($_GET['operation'])){ $operation = $_GET['operation']; } else { exit; }

    //check for compute
    if(isset($_GET['compute'])){ $compute = $_GET['compute']; } else { exit; }

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "regressiontest";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        switch($operation){
            case "managerFilter": {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("
                                    SELECT 
                                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (campaign_name) order by campaign_name asc) AS uniqueCampaignName,
                                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (test_type) order by test_type asc) AS uniqueTestType,
                                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (testee) order by testee asc) AS uniqueTestee,
                                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (testee_version) order by testee_version asc) AS uniqueTesteeVersion
                                    FROM
                                        regressiontest.campaign_run;
                                    ");                 
            } break;

            case "testcaseStatistics": {

                $testcaseId = $_GET['testcaseId'];

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("
                                    SELECT 
                                        terminal,
                                        AVG(runtime_ms) AS avg_runtime_ms,
                                        COUNT(id) AS count_runs,
                                        COUNT(CASE
                                            WHEN result = 0 THEN 1
                                            ELSE NULL
                                        END) AS passed_runs,
                                        COUNT(CASE
                                            WHEN result = 1 THEN 1
                                            ELSE NULL
                                        END) AS failed_runs,
                                        COUNT(id) - COUNT(CASE
                                            WHEN result = 0 THEN 1
                                            ELSE NULL
                                        END) - COUNT(CASE
                                            WHEN result = 1 THEN 1
                                            ELSE NULL
                                        END) AS aborted_runs,
                                        COUNT(CASE
                                            WHEN result = 0 THEN 1
                                            ELSE NULL
                                        END) / COUNT(id) * 100 AS success_rate,
                                        COUNT(CASE
                                            WHEN result = 1 THEN 1
                                            ELSE NULL
                                        END) / COUNT(id) * 100 AS fail_rate
                                    FROM
                                        tc_result
                                    WHERE
                                        tc_id = ".$testcaseId."
                                    GROUP BY terminal
                                    ");

            } break;

            case "testcaseRuns": {

                $testcaseId = $_GET['testcaseId'];

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("
                                    SELECT 
                                        tc_result.campaign_id,
                                        tc_result.tc_id,
                                        tc_result.id,
                                        tc_result.terminal,
                                        tc_result.createdate,
                                        tc_result.runtime_ms,
                                        tc_result.trx,
                                        tc_result.result,
                                        campaign_run.testee
                                    FROM
                                        tc_result
                                            INNER JOIN
                                        campaign_run ON tc_result.campaign_id = campaign_run.id
                                    WHERE
                                        tc_id = ".$testcaseId."
                                    ");

            }

        }


        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        $output = $stmt->fetchAll();

        switch($compute){
            case "json": {
                echo json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);              
            }
        }


    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Where do you set `$operation` and `$compute`?

Comment: they are set its only a part of the script im 100% sure

Comment: there is no error log, not on the page and not in the log file

Comment: [SELECT * FROM campaign_run limit 528;] this works not but this works [SELECT * FROM campaign_run limit 527;]

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `LIMIT 528` or `LIMIT 527` would make a difference.

Comment: BTW, use backticks around code in comments.

Comment: If there's a problem with the SQL, the `catch()` block will show the error message. The problem must be something else.

Comment: i tried it out when i limit it to 527 it works fine but 528 not. can you explain catch()?

Comment: [How to create an MCVE for a PDO related problem.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: @TobiasMeierDieWindows8Hilfe I mean this code: `catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }` You wrote it, don't you know what it does?

Comment: catch returns nothing- realy nothing: whole script: http://pastebin.com/FGbZMLzK